# Azure Function connectivity with app service which has windows authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

We have a scenario where we need to invoke, a restful API through azure functions. The restful API is hosted in MS azure under app services. Both web application and API are windows authentication enabled.

Azure function runs server less and it cannot pass windows authentication. Using certificate, I need to establish the connectivity with the endpoint. I need your inputs to understand, how we can establish the connectivity between Azure function and rest API which is Windows authentication enabled.

Comment: Just a confirm. Are your Web app/API using windows authentication for local AD accounts?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT  - Yes it is for local AD accounts.

Comment: I'm not very aware of your scenario and envrionment. But I can provide following suggestions: 1. Windows Authentication depends on Kerberos,which AAD doesn't support. 2.If you're using ADFS, you can integrate your on-premise with AAD to do federate SSO.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Also using AAD, you may be able to use Managed Service Identity ?

Comment: @Thomas For Azure function, you can use MSI.But I think it should not be a solution for this case. MSI is also works with AAD not local AD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions does not support Windows Authentication. If you need a function to be able to call into an external REST API, then you'll need to use a different authentication protocol, such as Azure Active Directory.

Comment: I am exploring your suggested approach. I will keep my analysis posted

Comment: Can you provide source for this statement, Chris? Would be nice :)

Comment: @SimonK. Sorry, I should have clarified that I am a member of the Azure Functions engineering team, so I'm speaking based on my personal understanding of the platform. I'm not aware of any official documentation that talks about this scenario.